# I am not able to search/filter images using a search bar in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uiimage, uisearchbar

I have a tableView and a searchbar on top, the custom made cell has an ImageView and a label, the text is pulled from a string Array and the picture from a UIImage array but when I try to filter the entries although I have achieved that with the strings ,I can't with the images.What I get when I search is the relevant string entry (for instance three entries starting with a 'c')but the filtered image entries are the first three images in the UIImage array for example.

```
import UIKit

let firstArray = [ "APC","Apple","Autonomic","Axis","B&W","BSS","Central","Sisco","Crestron","Crown","Denon","Digital","Direct Tv"]

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    //for search bar
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
  
    var filteredData: [String]!
    var filteredImages: [UIImage]!
    var searching = false

    var firstArray = [String]()

    var images = [UIImage(named:"APC"),UIImage(named:"Apple"),UIImage(named:"Autonomic"),UIImage(named:"Axis"),UIImage(named:"B&W"),UIImage(named:"BSS"),
                    UIImage(named:"Central"),UIImage(named:"Sisco"),UIImage(named:"Crestron"),UIImage(named:"Crown"),UIImage(named:"Denon"),
                    UIImage(named:"Digital"),UIImage(named:"Direct Tv")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //for search bar
        searchBar.delegate = self
        filteredData = firstArray
     
        firstArray = [ "APC","Apple","Autonomic","Axis","B&W","BSS","Central","Cisco","Crestron","Crown","Denon","Digital","Direct Tv"]
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if searching
        {
            return filteredData.count
        }else{
            return firstArray.count
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableTableViewCell

        Cell.textLabel?.textColor = .systemBlue
        Cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        
        if searching
        {
            Cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
            Cell.imageManuf?.image = self.images[indexPath.row]
            
        }else{
            Cell.textLabel?.text = firstArray[indexPath.row]
            Cell.imageManuf?.image = self.images[indexPath.row]
        }
        
        
        return Cell
        
    }

    //Mark: Search Bar config
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        filteredData = firstArray.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
        
        searching = true

        
        //to reload the data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

can you please help?I have all sort of problems with images, I don't seem to get a grasp with them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a struct, so that each string is "grouped" with the corresponding image. Each "string-image" pair represents something, right?

```
struct ImageWithName { // please think of a better name than this
    let image: UIImage
    let name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        image = UIImage(named: name)!
    }
}
```

Rather than storing two arrays, one for strings and one for images, you can just store one `ImageWithName` array:

```
var filteredData: [ImageWithName]!
var searching = false

var firstArray = [ImageWithName]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //for search bar
    searchBar.delegate = self
 
    firstArray = ["APC","Apple","Autonomic","Axis","B&W","BSS","Central","Cisco","Crestron","Crown","Denon","Digital","Direct Tv"]
        .map(ImageWithName.init(name:))
    filteredData = firstArray
}
```

In `cellForRowAt`, access `.name` and `.image`:

```
if searching
{
    cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].name
    cell.imageManuf?.image = filteredData[indexPath.row].image
        
}else{
    cell.textLabel?.text = firstArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.imageManuf?.image = firstArray[indexPath.row].image
}
```

In `textDidChange`, access `.name` to search the name:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredData = firstArray.filter({$0.name.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sweeper, yes they do, in the image array the names represent an image with that name in my Assets.Am I right to assume that I don't need to have the images array anymore since I have a struct that determines the correlation and this " .map(ImageWithName.init(name:)) "makes the connection to my assets? If this works it will help me so much with other stuff that I can't make them work by using a struct..

Comment: Correct. You don’t need the images array. You just need the array of `ImageWithName`. @georgebolarakis

Comment: -You are a magician!!! I was struggling for two days to fix it before I asked..I wish I could buy you a beer!!

Comment: Yes you were spot on!!Sorry but where is the checkmark?

Comment: Found it, I wasn't wearing my glasses and it was greyed out..Thank you again!